# Firestore: Can we not use orderBy on a field filtered with whereIn?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I get this error when tring to `orderBy` a field I have filtered with `whereIn(field,Array)`:

`FirebaseFirestoreException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter`

But there is no equality sign; there rather an OR between equalities, like field="xx" OR field="yy" OR field="zz".

Which makes it perfectly reasonable to want to order by the field.

Is it really not possible to use orderBy with whereIn on the same field??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whereIn` (also known as array-contains) is effectively a logical OR of several values checked for equality.  As you can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) (emphasis mine):

> Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 **equality** (`==`) clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An in query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values.

So, whereIn should be considered an **equality** filter.  The error message could be clearer about that, but I suspect it is left over from a time when there was no `in` operator available in Firestore.

To answer the question, no, it's not possible.

Comment: I think this is a bug in Firestore. I understand if it was whereEqual to single value, but not with an array. I have solved it by doing the sort afterwards in the adapter.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug at all - the documentation is pretty clear.  But you are free to file a bug report anyway.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I agree that this is a bug, or at the least an unwanted feature. For example, imagine you have a list of fruits with `color` properties. In the UI you have a filter that allows you to display only fruits of one or more colors -- and you have a sort that allows you to sort the fruits by color. Let's say you want to see only blue and red fruits -- and sort them by color. So the result would be blue and red fruits, in that order. You cannot do that now with the current limitations. So it's not such a strange use case, in my opinion, and it seems to be a relic from before they added `in`.

Comment: It's not so much a bug as an unfortunate limitation... Obviously they would allow it if they could.

Answer (score 0):

In using where and LimitToLast, I was forced to use OrderBy, to which `Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter` [that is hoisted upon the preceding where]

The solution to this is write on your documents, upon reading in another query, their status as a boolean, then you can `.where(titleAsArray,"array-contains",query.toLowerCase())` and `.orderBy("status","desc")` seriatim.

during development, make sure you use `.get().then(` instead of `.onSnapshot(`, as the boolean is updated when your parameters are met or not.